# TMENU in Typo3 - Modify href tag in menu item

Tags: menu, typo3, href, typoscript

Someone might be able to help here?

If Menu item on level 3 has subpages (class="has-children"), I would like to change the href tag to href="#0".

The TS looks like this:

```
        3 = TMENU
        3 {
            expAll = 1
            stdWrap.wrap = <ul>|</ul>

            NO = 1
            NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
            NO.allWrap.insertData = 1
            NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

            IFSUB = 1
            IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has-children">|</li>
            IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
            IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
```

HTML now looks like this:

```
           <ul>
                <li class="has-children">
                  <a href="/test/england">England</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test/ireland">Ireland</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
```

But should look like this:

```
           <ul>
                <li class="has-children">
                  <a href="#0">England</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="/test/ireland">Ireland</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
```

Any clues? Thanks for helping! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
        3 {
            expAll = 1
            stdWrap.wrap = <ul>|</ul>

            NO = 1
            NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
            NO.allWrap.insertData = 1
            NO.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title

            IFSUB = 1
            IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has-children">|</li>
            IFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
            IFSUB.doNotLinkIt = 1
            IFSUB.stdWrap.cObject = COA
            IFSUB.stdWrap.cObject {
                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                        field = nav_title // title
                        wrap = <a href="#0">|</a>                           
                }
            }
```

Works now!

Comment: correct me if I am wrong; in this way every link at that level has href="#0", is it good for you?

Comment: Yes, all <a>'s within a <li> with class="has-children" have now href="#0".